# Pandas Remove Duplicates from row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a CSV file which has multiple duplicate values in the row. I Would like to remove these duplicate values so I am only left with the unique values.

Dataframe:

```
 1                            2          3                   4           5                              6    
Bypass User Account Control  T3431      Elevated Execution   T3424      Bypass User Account Control    T3431
Local Account                T3523      Domain Account       T4252      Local Account                  T3523
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
  1                            2          3                   4           5                              6    
Bypass User Account Control  T3431      Elevated Execution   T3424      
Local Account                T3523      Domain Account       T4252
```

There are 100's of duplicate data in the rows and i would only like to see the unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each row to unique values with `unique`, output is `array`, so convert to `Series`:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()), axis=1)
print (df1)
                             0      1                   2      3
0  Bypass User Account Control  T3431  Elevated Execution  T3424
1                Local Account  T3523      Domain Account  T4252
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
print (df1)
                             0      1                   2      3
0  Bypass User Account Control  T3431  Elevated Execution  T3424
1                Local Account  T3523      Domain Account  T4252
```

Last for original columns names use:

```
df1.columns = df.columns[:len(df1.columns)]
```

Comment: Amazing thank you very much. is there a way i can keep my original headers in the file?

Comment: @Will - There should be different each Series, so you can add `df1.columns = df.columns[:len(df1.columns)]` if `df1` is output `DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(df.stack()
  .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())
  .unstack()
  .reset_index(drop=True))
```

result:

```
                             1      2                   3      4
0  Bypass User Account Control  T3431  Elevated Execution  T3424
1                Local Account  T3523      Domain Account  T4252
```